# Define marathon services listening interface

Tags: vpn, zookeeper, apache-mesos

I have a mesos install with 3 VPS.

I use a virtual private network for internal networking.

Everytime marathon starts and bind a service to a new port, it binds it to 0.0.0.0.

No matter if I had a http(s) load balancy security in front, every user can access any service by doing a simple `nmap`

Can't find anything in the doc.

Does anyone has the same issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use environment variable `LIBPROCESS_IP` set binding address. You can set it in `/etc/default/marathon` or any file that is sourced before starting Marathon service.

```
export LIBPROCESS_IP=10.0.0.1
```